# Is it OK to kill MRT.exe?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update

**EDIT**: Amazingly, as soon as I posted this, the `Cancel installation` button I had clicked about 10 minutes ago finally worked. I would still like to know if it's safe to kill MRT.exe though, in case this comes up again.

(Somewhat) related: https://serverfault.com/questions/67475/how-much-longer-will-mrt-exe-take

I am in the process of installing yet another windows update (Windows 7 x64) and it's stuck on

> Installing update 5/15...
>   Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool

Initially it opened a small dialog window that said something like `Checking archive` and was stuck at 0% for about 20 minutes, which I made the mistake of closing.

Looking in Process Explorer I see this
[image: Process Explorer]

In total Windows update has been stuck for about 40 minutes now, I'm pretty sure my computer has no malicious software (although I could run a virus scan to be sure). Therefore, is it ok to kill MRT.exe? Will this corrupt my Windows installation in any way?

Comment: killing MRT.exe will not corrupt your installation since its an optional component of Windows.

Answer (score 4):

It most likely wasn't stuck, but was scanning your drive(s) for malware.

That's what the MRT.exe does, it's Microsoft's monthly-updated Malicious software Removal Tool.

If you don't care about letting it scan your system for malware, then go ahead and cancel it.

Comment: So it's ok to kill it?